# Minidlna deamon has problems with accessing media folder on initialization

Tags: permissions, startup, minidlna

It took me some time to set up minidlna deamon on Ubuntu 18.04.1. The deamon finally works after starting up the machine and is discovered by my audio device though it still has problems with accessing the folder with media.

When I check minidlna status after starting up the machine I get the `minidlna.c:631: error: Media directory "/home/kidd/Music" not accessible [No such file or directory]` error message:

```
● minidlna.service - LSB: minidlna server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/minidlna; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-12-04 23:21:24 CET; 1min 44s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1290 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/minidlna start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/minidlna.service
           └─1461 /usr/sbin/minidlnad -f /etc/minidlna.conf -P /run/minidlna/minidlna.pid

gru 04 23:21:19 adze systemd[1]: Starting LSB: minidlna server...
gru 04 23:21:24 adze minidlna[1290]: [2018/12/04 23:21:24] minidlna.c:631: error: Media directory "/home/kidd/Music" not accessible [No such file or directory]
gru 04 23:21:24 adze systemd[1]: Started LSB: minidlna server.
```

After I restart minidlna with `sudo service minidlna restart` I get this:

```
● minidlna.service - LSB: minidlna server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/minidlna; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-12-04 23:23:26 CET; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1766 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/minidlna stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1774 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/minidlna start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/minidlna.service
           ├─1785 /usr/sbin/minidlnad -f /etc/minidlna.conf -P /run/minidlna/minidlna.pid
           └─1788 /usr/sbin/minidlnad -f /etc/minidlna.conf -P /run/minidlna/minidlna.pid

gru 04 23:23:26 adze systemd[1]: Starting LSB: minidlna server...
gru 04 23:23:26 adze systemd[1]: Started LSB: minidlna server.
```

and everything works fine.

The thing is I want minidlna deamon to see the media directory on startup so that I don't have to log in to terminal every time I reboot the server to restart the daemon and play music on my hifi.

It's not a question of permissions, because I'm running minidlna as root.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried putting an `@startup` cronjob that would restart the service for you automatically?  Perhaps the job is starting to early... ?  Maybe restarting at reboot from cron would circumvent... ?  Just throwing the idea out there, since no one has replied on this yet.

Comment: @reboot cronjob doesn't do it. Perhaps the job runs earlier than the system can access the space with music? 
`error: Media directory "/home/kidd/Music" not accessible [No such file or directory]`
How can I ensure a process runs after it can access the local disk space?

Comment: I found that someone was able to use `fstab` entries to get a workaround: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-minidlna-permission-denied/38915/4 but I can't get the logic behiind it.